# Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts in Postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, npgsql, pgadmin

I am using the following script to create function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fninsertreceipttransaction(
accountid1 integer,
customerid1 integer,
receiptid1 integer,
retailerid1 integer,
planid1 integer,
enteredat1 timestamp without time zone,
cardtype1 character varying,
last4digits1 integer,
receiptnumber1 character varying,
totalreceiptspend1 double precision,
transactiondate1 timestamp without time zone,
storeid1 integer,
title1 character varying,
message1 character varying,
enteredby1 character varying)
RETURNS typcounter
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$

declare 
    counter typcounter;
    planId1 int;
    cardid1 int;
    spendtargetmax1 double precision;
begin

-- insert receipt data
update tblreceipts
set

   ReceiptIssuedAt = transactiondate1,
    IsDownloaded = 't',
    IsProcessed  = 't',
    IsVerified1  = 't',
    IsVerified2  = 't',
    DownloadedAt = current_timestamp,
    ProcessedAt = current_timestamp,
    VerifiedAt1 = current_timestamp,
    VerifiedAt2 = current_timestamp,
    DownloadedBy = 'user1',
    ProcessedBy = 'user1',
    VerifiedBy1 = 'user1',
    VerifiedBy2 = 'user1'
where accountId = accountId1 and receiptId = receiptId1;

-- Check if there is active plan
-- when changing plan status, update actualCompletion date
-- Also update EOD process to include receipts
-- this should change depending on plan start and end condition

-- add transaction
select cardid into cardid1 from TblAccountCards 
    where accountid=accountid1
    and cardtype=cardtype1
    and last4digits=last4digits1;

update TblTransactions
set
    RetailerId = retailerId1,
    StoreId = storeid1,
    TransactionAt = transactiondate1,
    EnteredAt = enteredat1,
    UpdatedAt = current_timestamp,
    Subtotal = totalreceiptspend1,
    CardId =  cardid1
where accountId = accountId1 and receiptId = receiptId1;

-- roll up transactions to plan spent
update tblcustomerplans
set currentAmountSpent = (select sum(subtotal) from TblTransactions where 
                          accountId = accountId1 and planId = planId1)
where 
    accountId = accountId1 
    and customerId = customerId1;

select spendtargetmax into spendtargetmax1 from tblcustomerplans 
    where accountid=accountid1
    and customerid=customerid1
    and planid=planid1;

update tblcustomerplans
set status = 'MarkComplete'
where 
    accountId = accountId1 
    and customerId = customerId1
    and planId = planId1
    and currentamountspent >= spendtargetmax1;

select cast(1 as bigint) into counter;
return counter;
end

$BODY$;
```

And Executing the function with following query

```
DO $$ BEGIN
PERFORM fninsertreceipttransaction(31, 24, 56, 10001, 53, '2018-11-16 20:03:28', 'Mastercard', '3434', '203', 200, '2018-11-17 00:00:00', 1,
                                          'Receipt Trnasaction', 'Transaction Successfully Processed', 'Admin');

END $$;
```

Getting Error:

> ERROR:  function fninsertreceipttransaction(integer, integer, integer,
>   integer, integer, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer,
>   unknown, integer, unknown, unknown, unknown) is not unique

I had also back track all queries using static data

```
                --------------------------------                          
update tblreceipts
set

   ReceiptIssuedAt = '2018-11-17 00:00:00',
    IsDownloaded = 't',
    IsProcessed  = 't',
    IsVerified1  = 't',
    IsVerified2  = 't',
    DownloadedAt = current_timestamp,
    ProcessedAt = current_timestamp,
    VerifiedAt1 = current_timestamp,
    VerifiedAt2 = current_timestamp,
    DownloadedBy = 'user1',
    ProcessedBy = 'user1',
    VerifiedBy1 = 'user1',
    VerifiedBy2 = 'user1'
where accountId = 31 and receiptId = 53;
------------------------------------
select cardid from TblAccountCards 
    where accountid=31
    and cardtype='Mastercard'
    and last4digits=3434;
    ---------------------------------------
    update TblTransactions
set
    RetailerId = 10001,
    StoreId = 1,
    TransactionAt = '2018-11-17 00:00:00',
    EnteredAt = '2018-11-16 20:03:28',
    UpdatedAt = current_timestamp,
    Subtotal = 200,
    CardId =  1
where accountId = 31 and receiptId = 53;
--------------------------------------------
update tblcustomerplans
set currentAmountSpent = (select sum(subtotal) from TblTransactions where 
                          accountId = 31 and planId = 53)
where 
    accountId = 31 and customerId = 24;
------------------------------------------------------------------------
select spendtargetmax from tblcustomerplans 
    where accountid=31 and customerid=24 and planid=53;
   -------------------------------- 
update tblcustomerplans
set status = 'MarkComplete'
 where 
    accountId = 31 
    and customerId = 24
    and planId = 53
    and currentamountspent >= 550;
```

But Don't know why the Problem comes executing the function

Comment: Have you tried `PERFORM public.fninsertreceipttransaction(...`?

Comment: After creating the functionr,run  `\df public.fninsertreceipttransaction` from psql  do you see more than one row?

Comment: Not working with PERFORM public.fninsertreceipttransaction(... and \df public.fninsertreceipttransaction

Comment: What do you mean not working ? `\df public.fninsertreceipttransaction` is not giving you any output? I asked to check how many entries of that function do you see?

Comment: I am trying using pgadmin , its not giving any output having error.

Comment: Also Checked all queries are working but unable to run function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you have two or more functions already created with the name `fninsertreceipttransaction` and same number of arguments as passed during execution and Postgres is unable to determine which one should be called.

To illustrate, let's create 2 functions.

**Function1**

```
knayak= CREATE FUNCTION myfunction(p TIMESTAMP)
knayak- RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
knayak$ BEGIN
knayak$         RETURN true;
knayak$ END;
knayak$ $$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

**function2**

```
knayak=
knayak=
knayak= CREATE FUNCTION myfunction(p ) --unknown type p
knayak- RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
knayak$ BEGIN
knayak$         RETURN 1;
knayak$ END;
knayak$ $$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

Now try to execute the function by passing a string

```
knayak= DO $$
knayak$ BEGIN
knayak$  PERFORM myfunction('2018-11-16 20:03:28');
knayak$ END$$;
```

I get this error because Postgres can't decide between the two based on my arguments.

> ERROR:  function myfunction(unknown) is not unique LINE 1: SELECT
>   myfunction('2018-11-16 20:03:28')
>                  ^ HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts. QUERY:  SELECT
>   myfunction('2018-11-16 20:03:28') CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function
>   inline_code_block line 3 at PERFORM

Now, how to know which functions are present ?

If you are using **`psql`** command prompt, run this simple command.

```
knayak=# \df myfunction
                                List of functions
 Schema |    Name    | Result data type |      Argument data types      |  Type
--------+------------+------------------+-------------------------------+--------
 public | myfunction | integer          | p                             | normal
 public | myfunction | boolean          | p timestamp without time zone | normal
(2 rows)
```

You can see that there are two functions present with different arguments.

If you are using **PgAdmin**, running this query should give you same result.

```
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  p.proname as "Name",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_function_result(p.oid) as "Result data type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) as "Argument data types",
 CASE
  WHEN p.proisagg THEN 'agg'
  WHEN p.proiswindow THEN 'window'
  WHEN p.prorettype = 'pg_catalog.trigger'::pg_catalog.regtype THEN 'trigger'
  ELSE 'normal'
 END as "Type"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc p
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE p.proname OPERATOR(pg_catalog.~) '^(myfunction)$'
  AND pg_catalog.pg_function_is_visible(p.oid)
ORDER BY 1, 2, 4;
```

How should you drop one of the functions? Well, If you are sure you want only one function should be used and you have it's create function script, drop all and recreate it.

You cannot simply issue `DROP function <functionname>` which doesn't work in such cases. You'll have to specify the argument signature.

```
knayak=# DROP function myfunction; --Doesn't work
ERROR:  function name "myfunction" is not unique
HINT:  Specify the argument list to select the function unambiguously.
```

These statement work.

```
knayak=#
knayak=# DROP function myfunction(p);
DROP FUNCTION

knayak=# DROP function myfunction(timestamp);
DROP FUNCTION
```

After dropping, rerun the `create function` script only once. It should execute fine.